# How to get value of constraint after optimize model using Gurobi

Tags: c#, linear-programming, gurobi

I want to know the value of constraint `sumPj` for each index after the model if optimized. Here is the constraint:

```
for (int m = 0; m < M; m++)                
{
    for (int i = 0; i < C; i++)
    {
       GRBLinExpr sumPj = 0;
        foreach (int p in VehicleList[m])
        {
            sumPj.AddTerm(a[i].Column[p], z[p]);
        }
        master.AddConstr(sumPj <= y[m], "tj" + m + "," + i);
    }
}
```

I use `master.GetConstrByName("tj" + m + "," + i).Get(GRB.DoubleAttr.Slack)` but show wrong value.

Comment: What about `y[m]-slack`?

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen no, it does not work

Answer (score 0):

I have found it by myself. First, I should make sumPj as a multidimensional array.

```
GRBLinExpr[,] sumPj = new GRBLinExpr [M,C];
for (int m = 0; m < M; m++)                       
{

for (int i = 0; i < C; i++)
    {
        sumPj[m,i] = 0;
        foreach (int p in VehicleList[m])
        {
            sumPj[m,i].AddTerm(a[i].Column[p], z[p]);
        }
        master.AddConstr(sumPj[m,i] <= y[m], "tj" + m + "," + i);
    }
}
```

then I add the value after optimization by

```
for (int m = 0; m < M; ++m)
    {
      for (int i = 0; i < C; i++)
        {
          Console.WriteLine("C " + m + "," + (i + 1) + " " + sumPj[m,i].Value);
          Constraint[m, i] = sumPj[m,i].Value;
        }
    }
```